# Could not find Xcode project files in "ios" folder

Tags: react-native, expo

I cloned a react native project from gitlab . after cloning i got both android and ios folders in my react native project . i than run "npm install" to install node modules . after that when i run "react-native run-ios" it shows me error message that says "Could not find Xcode project files in "ios" folder"[image]

Comment: Well, if you see in the ios folder you don't have the .xcodeproj file, so the error is ok, maybe running pod install inside the ios folder to install all the pods could fix your problem

Comment: i can also see that file is missing -_- give me solution on how to resolve it